# Adding ?nocache=1 to every url (including the assets like stylesheet) behind the scenes using mod rewrite

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Alright, this is due to the pain that godaddy gives me by implementing their own caching in a MANAGED WORDPRESS hosting. I looked it up and as it turns out, their flush caching facility is not available to me in the wordpress dashboard as it is a subdirectory /wp/ installation.

Also, there is no setting to enable "development mode" which apparently turns off caching on the godaddy control panel.

But what I would like to do is to apply ?nocache=1 to every URL related to the site (including the assets like style.css) so that I get the non cached version of the files.

For example, if I put

> http://example.com/wp/wp-content/themes/example-theme/style.css

in the browser, I get a cached version of the stylesheet which does not reflect the recent one. But if I put..

> http://example.com/wp/wp-content/themes/example-theme/style.css?nocache=1

It shows up the most recent one.

Is this possible? If yes, could someone be kind enough to show me how? Perhaps Something like this... (it doesn't work!)..

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1?nocache=1 [R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could just change the name of your stylesheet ?

Comment: @thickguru How would that solve anything? It's not just THAT stylesheet which is a problem. Multiple assets face the same issue. I just used that as an example here.

Comment: For example, if your stylesheet was named `style.css`. That is what is is cached under. If you re-named it, for example, to `stylesheet.css`. Then the cached version would not show up. It works the same for cached pages.

Comment: Hmm I could do that but I'd have to do that with all the asset files that have changes in them. If there is no mod_rewrite way to do it, I'll have to resort to that.

Answer (score 1):

Try these rules to add required query parameter:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)nocache= [NC]
RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|ico|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ %{REQUEST_URI}?nocache=1 [R=302,L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: I just came across this question I had asked a while back. I am sorry about coming back to it so late. Anyhow, this did not work at the time I had tried it. I just tested it again on a test site out of curiosity but it still didn't work. Thanks for it, though!

Comment: How are you verifying that given rule is not working?

Comment: Hi Anubhav! Wow, you responded again, so kind of you! 

Well, i couldn't see the effect of the "nocache" GET value working. Everything was still cached and if I manually attached ?nocache=1 to the assets, it showed the uncached version. So I believe it was not being added automatically due to the rule.

Comment: Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Networking tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get. I believe you don't have any caching plugin installed in WP.

Answer (score 0):

They offered a code to disable it directly into your wp-config.php file.

Basically just add:

```
define( 'MWP_OBJECT_CACHE_DISABLED', true);
```

https://www.godaddy.com/help/object-caching-on-managed-wordpress-41408